# fullcalendar get events (json) with start,end current view params?

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to show events from the database per month according to the start and end parameters, but I can not achieve my goal, this is my code, any help?

```
 events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/asignacion/events.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:"POST",
            data: {

                start: start.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm'),
                end: end.format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm')
            },
            success: function(doc) {
              //alert(doc);
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        id: $(this).attr('start'),
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start'),
                        end: $(this).attr('end'),
                        cantidad: $(this).attr('cantidad')
                    });
                });
               callback(events);
            },
            error:function(doc){
              alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
$json = array();
date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");
$sql="SELECT id,title,start,end,cantidad FROM turnos_asignacion 
where start between '".$_POST["start"]."' and '".$_POST["end"]."' order by start asc";

$res=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $json[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: please specify your problem, "i can not achieve my goal" is not a very good problem description

Comment: events are not displayed, or errors found. that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start time and End time format should be like this "2014-11-09T16:00:00" .